# Azure: TypeScript compilation fails on build

Tags: azure, typescript

I had a project in which everything was compiling locally, but was unable to compile on the Azure Hosted Build Controller. Basically, the TypeScript compilation was failing with errors like

`Type 'any' is missing property 'create' from type '{ create: (args: any) => any; key: (args: any) => any; }'`

I hadn't changed anything in my code or my .csproj files so I knew something had changed on Azure's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the MSBuild output two different builds. The first build worked, and the second build (and all subsequent builds) failed.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe  --noImplicitAny --module amd --sourcemap --target ES5`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe  --noImplicitAny --module amd --sourcemap --target ES5`

Notice anything? The Hosted Build Controller is now not honoring my "compile with tsc 1.0" command and is just using whatever compiler is in its TypeScript folder. A change Azure made overnight and without any warning.

To fix this, I had to check my version of the TypeScript compiler into source control along with the TypeScript.Targets file used by MSBuild. More instructions on this [can be found here](http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/09/typescript-on-your-build-server.html).